# how to watch and record the information of all the registers such as `eax`,`ecx` and instructions cpu was executing?

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-registers

We would like to write code to watch and record the information of all the registers such as `eax`,`ecx` and instructions (we need to record all the instructions that the cpu is executing)  so that we can use Machine Learning  method to identify whether some instruction sequences are the Malicious instructions.

1. We used to alter `translate.c` from QEMU to record intermediate information including registers and instructions,that is to say ,we would record all the information while QEMU was translating instructions from the virtual machine on QEMU to real computer.
2. But collecting information from the virtual machine QEMU is more inefficient than the real machine,so we plan to write code so that we can collect all the information at Win10 on real computer.
3. The problem is that when we write code to obtain the value of `PC` register,the value is always the address of next line in our code,We don't know how to watch instructions(or code) of other parallel execution programs that CPU is executing?

would you mind to offer some ideas,thanks!

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: @user202729 Debugger can only attach one software,but we need to watch the whole  OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Precise Event Based Sampling (PEBS) feature of the Intel's CPUs.

PEBS enable storing architectural information, like the GP registers content, in a designed buffer each time a Performance Monitor Counter (PMC) trigger a Performance Monitor Interrupt (PMI).

PMCs can be set to trigger PMI base on a threshold.
PEBS can be enabled only on `IA32_PMC0` but that isn't a limitation.
It was introduced with the Intel Netburst architecture (Pentium 4) so it's available on each modern Intel's CPU.

Of the events for which PEBS is enabled, `INSTR_RETIRED.ANY_P` is probably the one you are looking for (Note: I don't think this counter increments in steps by one everytime but that should be minor noise/irrelevant for your analysis).

The PMI is dispatched through the Local APIC, so you have to look at it to translate it to an interrupt vector in order to attach an ISR to it.

PEBS requires some setup, particularly the Debug Store (DS) area and some meta-structure for storing the recordings.

By programming PMC0 to count the instructions retired (bonus, you can use different thresholds to tune the granularity of the recordings), by installing a PMI ISR that read PEBS records and save it to somewhere and finally by enabling PEBS you will be able to record the content of the registers.
Note that this must be done inside the OS, so you must be proficient with Windows internals and particularly the scheduler.
Plus the amount of information collected will be huge, thus there will still be a considerable slowdown of the system.

A nice side-effect of using PMCs is that you can enable them only for user-code, kernel-code or both if needed.

A complete reference of the PEBS feature can be found on Chapter 18 of the [Intel's Manual Volume 3](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.html).
Chapter 17 is propedeutic.

---

If PEBS is too cumbersome you can try experimenting with the `TF` that force the CPU traps on every instruction.
Combined with the Last Branch Recording (LBR) feature you can step jump-by-jump instead of instruction-by-instruction.
It also can be combined with the Task State Segment (TSS) & C. to automate some recording (like spilling the context into memory) upon the Trap interrupt.

I'm not aware, off the top of my head, of any other means to trace registers.
The Virtual Machine Extensions (VMX) are not useful since changing the GP registers doesn't use critical instructions.

Under Linux, one could look into [rr](http://rr-project.org/) but this is not your case.

If I may, maybe tracing register content at the system call boundary (e.g. by redirecting `syscall`, this is easy for a driver) is a better idea.
Processes change their registers constantly but ultimately only what they pass to system calls affect the system (this neglects 0-days and shared memory).